# what kind of bug is doing these holes?

Tags: bedroom

holes are popping up in walls and ceilings of both bedrooms

[image: enter]

[image]

Comment: The first picture looks like an infestation of the Phillips head screw.  They're known to make holes in all kinds of surfaces.

Comment: @fixer1234  is it the flesh eating screw worm?

Comment: `holes are popping up in walls and ceilings` .... really?  .... looks to me like you are not very observant and you take a long time to notice that screws are sticking out ... that first picture shows a screw that has been painted over, so it has been like that a long time

Comment: no this only hole with screw..first day it was hole only

Comment: then somebody put the screw there and painted over it .... it did not magically appear

Answer (score 2):

looks like the nails/screws that hold the drywall is popping. It's quite common especially with houses on shifting soils. If they are screws then run another screw next to/above or below then fill with spackel.